# No puedo cambiar el boton en efecto nocturno

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy trabajando sobre un efecto que es el modo nocturno pero mi problema es que sigue saliendo la palabra `sun` y `moon` cuando el efecto esta activo (en su lugar van dos iconos).

Funciona bien, pero deja la palabra sun cuando el modo oscuro esta activo y no puedo solucionarlo.

Agradezco de antemano!

```js
const btnSwitch = document.querySelector('#nightmode');

btnSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {
 document.body.classList.toggle('nigth');
 btnSwitch.classList.toggle('active');

 if(document.body.classList.contains('nigth')){
  localStorage.setItem('nigth-mode', 'true');
 } else {
  localStorage.setItem('nigth-mode', 'false');
 }
});

if(localStorage.getItem('nigth-mode') === 'true'){
 document.body.classList.add('nigth');
} else {
 document.body.classList.remove('nigth');
}
```

```css
body {
-webkit-transition: .3s ease all;
transition: .3s ease all;
}

body.nigth {
background-color: rgb(21, 32, 43);
color: #fff;
}

.btn-span {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/06494d4185.js"></script>
<span class="btn-span badge badge-primary" id="nightmode">
<i class="far fa-sun"></i>
<i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es cambiar el contenido del "botón" de acuerdo al modo seleccionado, si es normal asignas 'Sun' a `.innerText`, si es nocturno, asignas 'Moon', o viceversa, como prefieras.

```js
const btnSwitch = document.querySelector('#nightmode');

btnSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('nigth');
    btnSwitch.classList.toggle('active');

    if(document.body.classList.contains('nigth')){
        // Asignar contenido cuando estás en modo nocturno
        btnSwitch.innerText = 'Moon';
        localStorage.setItem('nigth-mode', 'true');
    } else {
        // Asignar contenido cuando estás en modo normal
        btnSwitch.innerText = 'Sun';
        localStorage.setItem('nigth-mode', 'false');
   }
});

// Ejecutar hasta que se cargue todo el contenido de la página
window.onload = function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('nigth-mode') === 'true'){
        btnSwitch.innerText = 'Moon';
        document.body.classList.add('nigth');
    } else {
        btnSwitch.innerText = 'Sun';
        document.body.classList.remove('nigth');
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    transition: .3s ease all;
}

body.nigth {
    background-color: rgb(21, 32, 43);
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-span {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<span class="btn-span badge badge-primary" id="nightmode">Sun</span>
```

Comment: Gracias Triby, en texto si funciona, lo que no logro hacerlo es con los iconos

Comment: Pero bueno, es lo menos los iconos, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Podrías poner los íconos con `<img>` y cambiar el atributo display, dependiendo del tema seleccionado.